# PHP Array - Return specific elements of array and display them on one line

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm about ready to go crazy with this one.  I can't seem to figure out how to print out elements of an array and then put all the results on one line (with a specific output).

Here's my array data (after running it through a `foreach` statement:

```
Array
(
    [hostname] => server01
    [server_id] => 4
    [disk_mountpoint] => /
    [disk_datetime] => 1426395600
    [disk_device] => /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
    [disk_capacity] => 15G
    [disk_used] => 5.3G
)
Array
(
    [hostname] => server01
    [server_id] => 4
    [disk_mountpoint] => /var
    [disk_datetime] => 1426395600
    [disk_device] => /dev/mapper/VolGroup01-LogVol00
    [disk_capacity] => 107G
    [disk_used] => 52G
)
Array
(
    [hostname] => server01
    [server_id] => 4
    [disk_mountpoint] => /opt
    [disk_datetime] => 1426395600
    [disk_device] => /dev/mapper/VolGroup02-LogVol00
    [disk_capacity] => 156G
    [disk_used] => 127G
)
```

Here's my `foreach` statement:

```
foreach ($storage_report as $item) {
                print_r($item);
}
```

I've spent a couple of hours trying to wrap my mind around a multi-dementional array as well as looking at some other peoples questions on StackOverflow, but nothing seems to fit what I'm trying to do.

By the way, the array above is actually output from a MySQL query and it returns only one unique `hostname`, so where it has the same hostname as an element, that is correct (same with the server_id).

I even tried a nested `foreach` loop and that didn't work well and I got confused again, so I didn't want to post it here.

Basically, with the data above, I want the output to look like:

```
$disk_mountpoint = $disk_used
```

With that being said, the ultimate output (if you were to parse what I just wrote), the final output would look like:

```
/ = 5.3G
/var = 52G
/opt = 127G
```

I feel like I'm over complicating things and wanted to know if someone could just point me in the right direction and help me out.

Thanks!
Drew

Answer (score 3):

um.. just:

```
foreach ($storage_report as $item) {
    echo $item['disk_mountpoint'] .'='.$item['disk_used'];

}
```

Comment: Dang it ... I told you I was over-complicating things.  I even have this working somewhere else in my code that I did with another set of data.  I think I over complicated things because I originally was getting all data from mysql, and so I was grouping by the `server_id` and so it became a multi-dementional array.  Therefore, I've been thinking with that mentality the entire time instead of just looking at what is obviously an easy single dementional array.

Comment: Especially after staring at code all day. You could also look at `implode()` for this sort of shiz

Comment: @Dagon He did, and spared us all.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah man over complication. Can't you just do

```
foreach ($storage_report as $item) {
   echo $item['disk_mountpoint']."=".$item['disk_used'];
}
```

Comment: Yea, I commented on @Dagon answer.  I had two different ideas going on and just got overwhelmed.

Answer (score 1):

If it is that I undestand, so:

```
foreach ($storage_report as $item) 
{
      if (isset($item['disk_mountpoint']) && isset($item['disk_used']))
      {
          echo $item['disk_mountpoint'] .'='. $item['disk_used']; 
      }
}
```

That will iterate the entire collection and will read the content of each cell only if it is set.

Comment: Even-though this code helps, please explain it a little bit more.

Comment: What part needs explain? I thinks that $item can have nulls cells like disk_mountpoint or disk_used if it can't be read.